# jenkins pipeline bash script file not found

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Below is the sample code I have in my pipeline file

```
node('ubuntu') {
stage ('build') {
withCredentials([[$class: 'AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding', credentialsId: 'terraform', accessKeyVariable: 'aws_access_key', secretKeyVariable: 'aws_secret_key']]) {
                   def command1 = $/"/packer/packer build -var 'aws_ami_image=${ami_image}' -var 'aws_access_key=${aws_access_key}' -var 'aws_secret_key=${aws_secret_key}' /packer/ubuntu/dummy-deploy.json"/$
                    res = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "${command1}")
                    sh("echo ${res}")
}
}
}
```

I'm getting file not found error. Remote node and master have /packer/packer and /packer/ubuntu/dummy-deploy.json

```
[dummy] Running shell script
+ '/packer/packer build -var '\''aws_ami_image=******'\'' -var '\''aws_access_key=****'\'' -var '\''aws_secret_key=****'\'' /packer/ubuntu/dummy-deploy.json'

/jenkins/workspace/dummy@tmp/durable-5492c9fb/script.sh: line 2: /packer/packer build -var 'aws_ami_image=ami-*****' -var 'aws_access_key=****' -var 'aws_secret_key=****' /packer/ubuntu/dummy-deploy.json: No such file or directory
```

script returned exit code 1

Comment: And.. `/packer/packer` exists and is executable?

Comment: yes it is executable..

Comment: adding script {} block solved the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry about mixing declarative and scripted pipelines..I started with scripting pipeline and ended up with declarative.

```
pipeline {
agent { node { label 'linux' } }
// Define Variables
environment { 
    ...
    ...
}
stages { 
 stage ('plan') {
        steps {
            script {
                ....
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

adding script {} block solved the problem

```
node('ubuntu') {
stage ('build') {
script {
}
}
}
```

Comment: Are you mixing up declarative and scripted pipelines?

Comment: It's frighteningly easy to mix them up unfortunately. Need more docs.

Comment: If the [official docs](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/) don't help you to understand the difference, I've a slide in [one of my presentations](https://www.slideshare.net/StephenKing/declarative-jenkins-pipelines) (slide 32).